# JavaScript hide and show Carousel

Tags: javascript, carousel

I have an img Carousel in my Website. I have one Button to show and hide the img Carousel. At the beginning the Img Carousel is closed.
What is wrong with my code?

```
function closeandopenImgCarousel(){
    if(document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display=="block"){
        document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display="none";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display=="none")
    {  
        document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display="block";
    }
}
```

In the HTML part, I have the `onclick="closeandopenImgCarousel()`

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
```

Comment: Did you try debugging with your browser? Also, is your carousel id = "myCarousel" ? If you could show the carousel's HTML  it will help people solve your issue for sure :) .

Comment: I have added the tml code

Comment: you might want to revisit your conditionals. display=="block" rather than display="block" perhaps.

Comment: It dont help.
I show the Carousel, but it dont hide it again

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis at `if(document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display="none"))`. Remove it: `if(document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display="none")`

Comment: as @tys suggested, single `=` sign is for _assignment_ purposes and `==` is used for _comparison_ purposes. it seems you have a single `=` sign in your `if` clause (i.e. the expression inside the round `(` and `)` parentheses). changing that to `==` should fix your problem.

Comment: Yeah i see it, i have already removed it, still no changes.. like by 2pac..

Comment: both blocks are executing, so it's hiding then showing again. add an "else" to the second if statement to make it an "else if" so only one statement executes.

Comment: ha :D I think I know why it is not working :) remove the second `if` clause and use it as an `else` of your first `if` clause :)

Comment: my god, I missed that... it should work now for him

Comment: Yeeahh now its work.
I added and else to the seconde if statement.
With only an else it dont work.
Thank you guys! peace!

Comment: @saamii: for your future reference: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qx5n6Lj/)**.

Comment: @ Tahir Ahmed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function closeandopenImgCarousel(){
  if(document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display=="block"){
    document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display="none";
  } else {
     document.getElementById("myCarousel").style.display="block";

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer as requested, plus some clean up:

```
function closeAndOpenImgCarousel() {
    var carousel = document.getElementById("myCarousel");
    if (carousel.style.display == "block")
        carousel.style.display = "none";
    else if (carousel.style.display == "none")
        carousel.style.display = "block";
}
```

Alternatively..

```
function closeAndOpenImgCarousel() {
    var carousel = document.getElementById("myCarousel");
    carousel.style.display = (carousel.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}
```